# My display goes blank after the initial windows 10 logo

Tags: windows, windows-10, hdmi, vga

ihave a vga monitor which is connected to a gigabyte b450m motherboard via a hdmi to vga converter. it is running a ryzen 3 2200g processor. my monitor's resolution is 1680x1050. when the initial logoo of the motherboard manufacturer comes up, the screen as a whole is shifted to the left. after that the windows 10 loading icon comes up and then the screen is blank. i have the amd drivers installed. when i unplug and then replug the hdmi to vga converter, the screen comes up magically. am i missing any display drivers or bios settings??.

Comment: 1680x1050 is quite a high resolution. Can you try again with a lower one?

Comment: It actually works with Windows 7

Comment: So the same setup is working in Windows 7, but not in 10. What can we say? Yet another issue related to Windows 10.

Comment: Ya. What are my options. Maybe remove the latest windows updates and see if it's working

Comment: Dunno. Did you have a reason to update to the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System?

Comment: Sorry. When I meant it worked on Windows 7 I meant that it worked on a different machine. Sorry. I researched online and found out that the Mobo cpu combo might be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out the problem. The monitor had to be turned on before the computer and left on for a few seconds. Then if I turn on the pc, the pc works like a normal one. It was a monitor issue. I tried another monitor and that worked without Any issues